Why can't delete QThread pointer by using deleteLater?
Here is a simple example:
work.h
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(QObject *parent = 0):QObject(parent){}
    ~Worker(){
        qDebug()<<"work destruct";
    }
public slots:
    void work(){
        qDebug() << "Worker_x:"<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
};
#endif // WORKER_H

MyObject.h
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyObject(QObject *parent = 0):QObject(parent)
    {
        qDebug() << "MyObject::member1():"<<"ThrID:"<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
    ~MyObject(){
        qDebug()<<"object destruct";
    }
signals:
    void callWorker();
};
#endif // MYOBJECT_H

QMainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<"GUI threadID:"<<QThread::currentThreadId();
    obj = new MyObject;
    w = new Worker();
    t = new QThread;
    w->moveToThread(t);
    connect(t,&QThread::finished,w,&QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(t,&QThread::finished,t,&QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(t,&QObject::destroyed,this,&MainWindow::setThread);
    connect(obj,&MyObject::callWorker,w,&Worker::work);
    t->start();
    emit obj->callWorker();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    if(t->isRunning()){
        qDebug()<<"in destruct";
        t->quit();
        t->wait();
    }
    delete obj;
}

void MainWindow::setThread(){
    qDebug()<<"thread destructed";
}

In this program,when I close mainwindow,I get these messages:
GUI threadID: 0xe78
MyObject::member1(): ThrID: 0xe78
Worker_x: 0x16ec
in destruct
work destruct
object destruct
I think QThread pointer t doesn't get deleted.If I use QThread object like QThread t,then I can see thread destructed message.Why pointer of QThread can't trigger deleteLater slot of itself,but an instance can? Or how should I change my program?
